# RankCSE paper and i cannot get started. Keep crashing at building wheel for tokenizers(pyproject.toml)

Tags: python-3.x, rust-cargo, pyproject.toml

So the paper has an unofficial code posted on Git Hub.
https://github.com/perceptiveshawty/RankCSE

I started a virtual environment and am trying to pip install -r requirements.txt but the code always crashes at the same point.

Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.

With the output error being
Downloading crates ...
error: failed to download `crossbeam-deque v0.8.5`

```
  Caused by:
    unable to get packages from source

  Caused by:
    failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\Vaanavan\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\crossbeam-deque-0.8.5\Cargo.toml`

  Caused by:
    failed to parse the `edition` key

  Caused by:
    this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
  error: `cargo metadata --manifest-path Cargo.toml --format-version 1` failed with code 101
```

I tried checking the rust and cargo versions.
However my cargo and rust are up to date
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)

Cant seem to figure out how to fix this

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @ViKiG : managed to fix it by depreciating the python version to 3.8.6. Cant find any other fix for it as of now